# How to repeatedly search and increment a value in a text file

Tags: regex, perl, loops, text, replace

I have to search and increment certain data from a text file. I could extract and print out the data, but I am not sure on how to update/increment it.

There is data on a line in the file that I want to increment by 15% in a loop.

```
+xyz0 = 0.5 tg = 0.512 kjkj = 7543
```

I want to increment the value beside `abc0` in a loop, 15% each time, write it to a text file, run it and repeat.

```
open my $fh, "<" , ".....lib" or die "$!";

for ( my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {

    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) { 

        if ( my ($xyz0) = $line =~ m/xyz0 = (\S+)/ ) {
              print $xyz0, "\n"; # this prints 0.005 
              $new_value = $xyzo * 1.15; 
              $xyz0 =~ s/$xyz0/$new_value/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had invested just 30 seconds of googling, you probably would have found the answer on your own: [perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Turn on use strict and use warnings and that'll tell you that you've written `$xyzo` when you may have meant `$xyz0`

Also - you're doing a replacement on `$xyz0` and not `$line`:

```
 $xyz0 =~ s/$xyz0/$new_value/
```

It'll work, but as it goes out of scope immediately after, it won't have actually done anything useful.

Maybe you meant:

```
$line =~ s/$xyz0/$new_value/;
```

Although if your line is more complicated than just having that value on there, you do run the risk of 'hitting' the wrong value in there. (e.g. if `$xyz0` is the same value as another thing on the line). You may want to do:

```
$line =~ s/xyz0 = (\S+)/xyz0 = $new_value/;
```

`\S+`  is a bit of a crude way to catch what you want though - it catches 'non whitespace' but that can be things that *aren't* numbers, and so mutiplying by 1.15 is going to produce bogus results. It's probably better to use `\d+` or `[\d\.]+` to reduce the odds of that happening. (Technically `[\d\.]+` matches any combination of dots and numbers, so `1.2.3.4` is valid. But it's still better than `\S`)

Comment: After you've done this, `$line =~ s/xyz0 = (\S+)/xyz0 = $new_value/;` how can I write it back to the text file ?

Comment: Write it to a new file, copy it over the original.